Not getting passwordless signin emails from Firebase auth
For some reason, I have stopped getting passwordless signin emails from Firebase auth on a website. I can't use other social providers there because it errors saying "An account already exists with email auth provider". I suppose to link a different federated auth provider, I'll anyways need access to my current account first, which I'm unable to.
What option do I have to get back access to my account again? Is there some way to manually generate a login link for a particular account from backend?
